# Stream value error : Null value received on adding documentsnapshot to BehaviorSubject/ordinary stream

Tags: firebase, flutter, rxdart

```
BehaviorSubject<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> getDailyTasks() {
    var stream = db.collection("Daily_tasks").doc(user!.uid).snapshots();

    todoStreamController.sink.addStream(stream);
    print(todoStreamController.value.data()); // returns null

    return todoStreamController;
  }
```

The above code snippet exposes the repository layer of my bloc(architecture) based application. From the repository layer the stream is used in the streambuilder based UI class.

**Attached is the link to the minimal reproduction sample** : https://github.com/Pranavvks/Ultimate-to-do-minimal-repd